# UWP toast notifications image from Bitmap

Tags: uwp

I'd like to show a toast notification using an image either from a Bitmap or thumbnail of a local file. The examples only show images from a web url. How can I directly set the image using a Bitmap?

Edit: Apparently ms-appdata does not work either. Based on the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts, as well as my own testing, only url src is accepted?

Comment: The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-toast-schema#toastgenericapplogo) says `The URL to the image. ms-appx, ms-appdata, and http are supported. Http images must be 200 KB or less in size.` So, how to use the `ms-appdata` when you send toast? Please post some code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, every file stored inside the app's folders (`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder`, `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder`, `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`) has it's one `ms-appdata://` uri.

So, I would suggest you to write the Bitmap file locally in the `TemporaryFolder` and use the `ms-appdata://` uri as follows: `ms-appdata:///temp/{imagename}.png`

More info here: [Create, write, and read a file - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)

EDIT

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-toast-schema#toastgenericapplogo), you can see how the schema of the Toast content is, and it says that you can use a local URI in the `ms-appdata` format as an image inside a Toast Notification.

Example for Hero images inside it (If you are specifying the Toast in C# instead of xml):

```
new ToastBindingGeneric() //The toast you want to show
{
    HeroImage = new ToastGenericHeroImage()
    {
        Source = "ms-appdata:///temp/yoursavedimage.png" //This is the image stored locally
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think ms-appdata works for UWP toasts (please correct me if I'm wrong). Edited the question.

Comment: ms-appdata:///temp/ didn't work for me, the only one that did was  ms-appdata:///local/ which is a bummer as that gets synced with the cloud.